# Problem Displaying Bootstrap Modal in ASP.NET Core Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap5-modal

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and trying to figure out how to display a Bootrstap modal based on a string property of the underlying page Model (Model.Message).  I've tried several different things and nothing is working.  Below is a sample Bootrstap modal I found on the Bootstrap website.  I can get the modal to display with a button, but that's not the functionality I am looking for.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="UserDialog" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Added code to my scripts section at the bottom of the page and a new JavaScript function in an external .js file.

Here's my scripts section on the Razor page

```
@section scripts
{    
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowModalDlg();

        var message = '@Model.Message';

        if (message != "") {
            ShowModalDlg();
        }           

    });

   </script>
}
```

Here's the new JavaScript function in my external file

```
function ShowModalDlg()
{
    $("#UserDialog").modal("show");
}
```

The ShowModalDlg() function does get called when it is supposed to, but the bootstrap modal is not showing.  The button I added to test "showing" the modal still works.  I also added (although not shown here) a temporary call to alert("I'm here!") inside of the ShowModalDlg() function and the alert shows perfectly.  I did just check the Chrome debug console and I am getting an error that seems to indicate I am loading jquery twice.  That error message is:

"$(...).modal is not a function"

So it looks like I need to figure out where that's happening.

I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, this kind of approach might solve your problem. We define a ShowModal variable sent from the controller as a javascript variable, then we trigger the modal by checking the value of this variable.

**EDIT:** We expect `'show'` string as showModal variable from controller.

```
<script>
    var showModal = '@Model.showModal';
    if(showModal == 'show'){
        $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
    }
</script>
```

---

If you use it this way it will work. You can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hv3x4Ly9/1/).

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- You may not really need this.  -->

<!-- Bootstrap 5 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/) -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work for me.  See my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by combining the answer above with the following:

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    var message = '@Model.Message';
    if (message != "") {
        ShowModalDlg();
    }
});
```

I should not have had that code inside of document ready, which is why it wasn't working and also causing the error message.